# Use of OR operator in python lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

There is a code example in the O Reilly Programming Python book which uses an OR operator in a lambda function. The text states that "[the code] uses an or operator to force two expressions to be run".

How and why does this work?

```
widget = Button(None, # but contains just an expression
text='Hello event world',
command=(lambda: print('Hello lambda world') or sys.exit()) )
widget.pack()
widget.mainloop()
```

Comment: This only works for functions that return a "falsey" value and to me that means its non-obvious and so bad form.

Comment: I just lost a lot of respect for that textbook...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every funnction in Python returns a value. If there is no explicit return statement it returns `None`. `None` as boolean expression evaluates to `False`. Thus, `print` returns `None`, and the right hand side of the `or` expression is always evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

The Boolean `or` operator returns the first occurring truthy value by evaluating candidates in sequence from left to right. So in your case, it is used to first print `'Hello lambda world'` since that returns `None` (considered falsey), it will then evaluate `sys.exit()` which ends your program.

```
lambda: print('Hello lambda world') or sys.exit()
```

---

[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#or):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.